# chromeos - chrome can't reach 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I am on chromebook and testing php web server from Termux via

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t /sdcard/Download/webserver
```

I tried to open the webpage in Chrome (127.0.0.1:8080) but it returned this error message: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. It works on Firefox and even Chrome Beta browsers via android so I know the web server is up and running. I've cleared caches, flushed DNS and done whatever solutions google search came up with and none works. What's up with Chrome? Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android apps run from an isolated environment on ChromeOS, you will need to get the ip address. From termux, try `ifconfig arc0` and look up the ip address and use that instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: wow, thank you.  I'd been looking for this answer for weeks and I'm not sure why I hadn't come across this response but it definitely worked.  It's a shame that we have to rely on a specific IP address instead of just `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`, but considering I'm in `termux` on ChromeOS, I'll take it!  Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, what's interesting is the fact that accessing `127.0.0.1` works for Firefox but *not* for Chrome.  You'd think it should either succeed or fail for both the same way.

Comment: This works, when you're online. When offline, there's no external IP to work with unfortunately.

Comment: For me on ChromeOS 98 the interface is eth0... I wish this was mapped to an easy to remember hostname on the ChromeOS side, or portforwarded to loclahost like linux is.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was termux `pkg install iproute2` and run `ip --json addr show eth0`

This clearly and reliably dumps the ipaddress in JSON format to ip.json.

Example:

```js
import { execSync } from 'child_process'
import { readFile } from 'fs'
const ipShowRaw = execSync('ip --json addr show eth0', {encoding: 'utf-8'})
// readFile('./ip.json', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, (e, data) => ipShow = JSON.parse(data))
const ipShow = JSON.parse(ipShowRaw)
const ip = ipShow[0]['addr_info'][0].local

console.log(ip)
```

From running from bash:

```sh
~ $ pkg install iproute2
~ $ node getIp.mjs
100.115.92.2
~ $ xdg-open 'http://100.115.92.2:8080'
```

The last line will typically open a new tab on ChromeOS's chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Local domains to be accessed is probably not allowed in your chrome. Go to chrome://flags and set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser.

Have a look at this [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224215#c2) as well.

Comment: I saw this solution before but there isn't "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" in chrome://flags anymore. Anyway this issue is resolved now.

Comment: For posterity: I hit this issue running `jupyter notebook` using ChromeOS's native Linux support, and the accepted answer of `ifconfig arc0` wasn't recognized. I saw this and thought the "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost" Chrome flag might have done it instead, but it also didn't work: the only solution was to close other Chrome tabs. See https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3764#issuecomment-438786434.